# Which European country sent the most slaves to the Americas?

Tags: slavery

I'm asking for a history project; I have searched online, but have been unable to find an answer.

Comment: You should explain what you are looking for. Is the country defined as A) the country receiving (buying) the slaves? B) the nationality of the ship? C) the nationality of the captain of the ship? D) the country owning the factory in Africa?

Comment: "Sending" is the act of dispatching something (somebody) on its way. So your question means "which body in Africa* dispatched most slaves to the Americas". Which is not the same thing at all as who transported them or who owned the ships or who crewed the ships or who received them at the other end. *I assume you mean Africa?

Comment: Writing a question in a title is a terrible practise. It shows a total lack of respect for people reading your question.

Comment: @SJuan76 Your (A) is obviously wrong: why would somebody write "send" if they meant "receive"? (C) seems completely irrelevant.

Comment: Writing a question in a title is courteous; it demonstrates clarity and focus, communicates what you want to know, and helps readers find questions they want to research.

Comment: I think there's a fundamental problem with the question, in that it assumes the slave trade was run by nations, instead of by individuals & companies.

Answer (score 13):

**Portuguese ships carried more slaves to the Americas than any other flag carrier**, but the numbers cited include Brazilian carriers

*Although the time periods for the two sources cited are different, both include the years when the large majority of slaves were transported*

[Number of slaves Embarked (E) & Disembarked (D), 1501 to 1866](http://www.slavevoyages.org/assessment/estimates)

1. **Portugal / Brazil    (E) 5.85 million, (D) 5.10 million** *Note: Brazil only became independent in 1822, by which time  the numbers embarked / disembarked were 4.34 million / 3.82 million*
2. Britain              (E) 3.26 million, (D) 2.73 million
3. France               (E) 1.65 million, (D) 1.38 million
4. Spain / Uruguay      (E) 1.06 million, (D) 0.88 million
5. Netherlands          (E) 0.55 million, (D) 0.48 million

This (older) source gives different numbers, but the top two flag carriers are the same.

[Number of Slaves Transported by each European Country, 1440 to 1870](http://www.slaverysite.com/Body/facts%20and%20figures.htm)

1. **Portugal / Brazil    4.65 million**
2. Britain              2.60 million
3. Spain / Cuba         1.60 million
4. France               1.25 million
5. Netherlands          0.50 million

Comment: @RonJohn Hitchhikers?

Comment: @RonJohn We only brought the pregnant women accross the ocean

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia has a table of [Destination of enslaved Africans (1519–1867)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slavery_in_the_United_States):

```
Destination                                           Percentage
British mainland North America                             3.7%
British Leeward Islands                                    3.2%
British Windward Islands and Trinidad (British 1797–1867)  3.8%
Jamaica (Spanish 1519–1655, British 1655–1867)            11.2%
Barbados (British)                                         5.1%
The Guianas (British, Dutch, French)                       4.2%
French Windward Islands                                    3.1%
Saint-Domingue (French)                                    8.2%
Spanish mainland North and South America                   4.4%
Spanish Caribbean islands                                  8.2%
Dutch Caribbean islands                                    1.3%
Northeast Brazil (Portuguese)                              9.3%
Bahia, Brazil (Portuguese)                                10.7%
Southeast Brazil (Portuguese)                             21.1%
Elsewhere in the Americas                                  1.1%
Africa                                                     1.4%
```

So... Portugal then?

Comment: Hm. Portuguese as destination is on thing, but who sailed the ships? The Spanish, the British, the French?

Comment: I thought that each colonial power (more or less) had their own ships & African bases. Did the Portuguese not have ships?